# Rewriting product to a binomial

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I'm currently researching Wigner matrices. I wanted to calculate the moments of its spectral density. The probability density is 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{4-x^2} \text{ for } x \in [-2,2] $$

I have found an expression for the $k^{th}$ moment by integrating
$$ \int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^k}{2\pi} \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx.$$

This is $0$ if $k$ is uneven and 
$$ \frac{\prod _{i=1}^{\frac{k}{2}} \frac{4k - 8i +12}{k - 2i +4}}{k+1}$$ if $k$ is even.

It is known that the moments are the Catalan numbers for k is even $$ \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}. $$ In Mathematica i found that my solutions are the Catalan numbers. But I can't figure out how to rewrite my product to the expression of the Catalan numbers. Which would be a way more intuitive expression.

Are there any tricks one can use to write products to binomials?

Comment: There is some index confusion. For $k = 2$, the integral yields $1$, the product yields $1/3$ and the last ( with the binomial ) yields $1$. I was trying to find an answer so far.

Comment: Yes I also spotted that index confusion.... for last expression $k=2$ then $\frac{1}{3} \frac{4!}{2! 2!} = 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have to consider $k$ even, we set $k=2l$ and show

> The following is valid for $l\geq 1$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2l+1}\prod_{i=1}^l\frac{8l-8i+12}{2l-2i+4}=\frac{1}{l+1}\binom{2l}{l}
> \end{align*}
>   with $\frac{1}{l+1}\binom{2l}{l}$ the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2l+1}\prod_{i=1}^l\frac{8l-8i+12}{2l-2i+4}
> &=\frac{1}{2l+1}\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}\frac{8l-8i+4}{2l-2i+2}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2l+1}\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}\frac{8i+12}{2i+4}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2l+1}\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}\frac{2(2i+3)}{i+2}\\
> &=\frac{2^l}{2l+1}\cdot\frac{(2l+1)!!}{(l+1)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{2^l}{l+1}\cdot\frac{(2l)!}{l!\cdot(2l)!!}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{l+1}\cdot\frac{(2l)!}{l!l!}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{l+1}\binom{2l}{l}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index $i$ by one
- In (2) we reverse the order of multiplication $i \rightarrow l-1-i$
- In (3) we use factorials and *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* instead of the product symbol
  \begin{align*}
  (2l+1)!!=(2l+1)(2l-1)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we use the identity 
  $
  (2l)!=(2l)!!(2l-1)!!
  $
- In (5) we use the identity
  \begin{align*}
  (2l)!!=(2l)(2l-2)\cdots 4\cdot 2=2^l\cdot l!
  \end{align*}

*Note:* In OPs question the case $k$ even should be written as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\frac{k}{2}+1}\binom{k}{\frac{k}{2}}
\end{align*}
in order to be consistent with the stated product expression.

Comment: @user84413: Thanks for your nice comment! :-)